# Is there a way to stop Application.Speech?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform that has a button that once pressed, reads out the text on it. A user can press 'Next' that hides the original text boxes then shows a set of new text boxes.

The problem I am having is that it will continue to read the old text instead of the new text. I have inserted the 'Purge' at the end of the code. But it throws an error

```
Private Sub AudioOnBtn_Click()
Sheets("Control").Range("Audio") = "x"

Application.Speech.Speak Label4.Caption
Application.Speech.Speak Label5.Caption
Application.Speech.Speak Label6.Caption

End Sub

 Private Sub BackBtn_Click()
Label1.Visible = False
Label2.Visible = False
Label3.Visible = False
Image1.Visible = False
BackBtn.Visible = False
CloseBtn.Visible = False


NextBtn.Visible = True
Label4.Visible = True
Label5.Visible = True
Label6.Visible = True

Application.Speech.Speak Label4.Caption, purge:=True
Application.Speech.Speak Label5.Caption
Application.Speech.Speak Label6.Caption

End Sub
Private Sub CloseBtn_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub NextBtn_Click()


Label1.Visible = True
Label2.Visible = True
Label3.Visible = True
Image1.Visible = True
BackBtn.Visible = True
CloseBtn.Visible = True


NextBtn.Visible = False
Label4.Visible = False
Label5.Visible = False
Label6.Visible = False


Application.Speech.Speak Label1.Caption, purge:=True
Application.Speech.Speak Label2.Caption
Application.Speech.Speak Label3.Caption


End Sub
```

[image]

What I would like is that it stops reading the text from the first piece of code and starts the next lot of text that needs reading.

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)
please always add your code as text formatted as code block.

Comment: I tried with `Application.Speech.Speak Me.Label1.Caption, True, , True` And that worked. If `SpeakAsync` isn't true, the method waits for the text to be spoken before continuing, which is probably why the next one won't cut it off. Not sure what your error is. Which line is throwing it?

Answer (score 1):

*expression*.Speak (*Text, SpeakAsync, SpeakXML, Purge*)

If `SpeakAsync` is `false`– which is default – the method waits for the text to be spoken before continuing, which is probably why the next one won't cut it off.
But with `SpeakAsync` being `true` it won't wait for it to finish, so running multiple speech after each other would result in only the last being read out.

So instead of doing:

```
Application.Speech.Speak Label4.Caption, purge:=True
Application.Speech.Speak Label5.Caption
Application.Speech.Speak Label6.Caption
```

Try:

```
Application.Speech.Speak Label4.Caption & Label5.Caption & Label6.Caption,True, , True
```